# Focusing a TextField causes LayoutConstraint errors in Super Simple SwiftUI app

Tags: swiftui, textfield

Super simple SwiftUI app produces`[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints`  log messages when you focus the text field. Is this a framework bug? Any suggestions for a workaround?

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct DemoApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()            
        }
    }
}


struct SearchBar: View {
    @State var queryString : String = ""
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            TextField("Station Name", text: $queryString)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View{
    var body: some View{
        NavigationView{
            SearchBar()
            Text("Empty here")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see such log with your code. Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints with keyboard and UIToolBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62455042/unable-to-simultaneously-satisfy-constraints-with-keyboard-and-uitoolbar)

Comment: Same issue in 14.4/5.8 as of 4/19/2023

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce in 14.3 Apparently it has been fixed.